# Is there a problem obfuscating classes that are Serializable/Parcelable?

Tags: android

Just wondering if we allow obfuscation of Serializable/Parcelable classes to get obfuscated by proguard, is there any problem while passing those objects in Bundle/Intents? Or its fine?

Comment: By default proguard obfuscate all the classes in your project. Coming back to the answer, no it does not create any problem.

Comment: It will be a problem if you are trying to pass them between apps, as they may not get obfuscated the same way.

Comment: Great. I only have passing happening inside my own app. Thanks guys :)